# Do I need to initialize a SQL connection every time in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Every time I create a project / analysis, I set up a connection to our SQL warehouse in my first markdown chunk so the following sql chunks can work. It's pretty redundant and I have a feeling there's a better practice here, yet I can't find anything online. Even if I set up my connection in another file to clean things up, and call `source` on it, I still need to make that file for every new project - curious if there's another way to deal with this!

Comment: One does not generally need to create a connection for each query ... and with many non-data-heavy uses, it is generally very little overhead to do so. If your DBA is complaining or you find the time it takes to initiate a connection is palpable, then please expand your question with something concrete and reproducible. If not, then perhaps it is not broken enough to try to fix. (As a side note, since you're asking about "better practices" with regards to SQL access, one good read is https://db.rstudio.com/, particularly under the "Best Practices" section.)

Comment: So I'm not creating a connection for query, just defining it once at the top of each project. But the act of creating it for every single project seems redundant, and don't know if there's a way around that

Comment: [This maybe something](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE) maybe Studio Code snippets would be a good idea for defining the SQL connection each time with a simple code snippet

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a go! Thanks @DanielJachetta